# Style problems when printing page

Tags: html, css

I have a problem when wanting to display the print preview of a page. This is how it looks in the browser.

[image]

And this is how it looks when I vizualize the previous image I want to print.

[image]

These are the styles that I use. And probe with "media = 'print'". Also adding 
!Important; at the end of style

```
<!-- Latest Bootstrap min CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/REDRIM/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">       
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Berkshire+Swash' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>      
    <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/REDRIM/assets/fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- magnific popup CSS --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/REDRIM/assets/css/magnific-popup.css">
    <!-- timeline CSS -->   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/REDRIM/assets/css/timeline.css">  
    <!-- animate CSS -->        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/REDRIM/assets/css/animate.css">       
    <!-- Style CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/REDRIM/assets/css/style.css">     
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/REDRIM/assets/css/responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/REDRIM/assets/bootstrap/css/print.css" media="print">
```

What I want is to remove the link that appears on the label

```
 a{outline: none !important;
    color: #337ab7;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;}
```

Try the following style, but I link when generating the preview to print still appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have something in your style sheet telling it to print with the link in parentheses. Remove the code that looks like this:

```
a[href]:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")"
}
```

Or you can override it with this:

```
@media print {
  a[href]:after {
    content: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the answer: those links aren't just showing up on their own. They are being put there by CSS exactly like this. Best to find that css and eliminate it. Overriding it will work, but then you've got pointless css sitting around somewhere waiting to bite you in the butt in some unexpected way.

Comment: Thanks...I worked. But in the end was just remove the few labels "@media print" that were in the file "bootstrap.min.css". Anyway thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't delete code from the bootstrap style sheet because you don't know what effects it will have. It's better to just write your own custom style sheet and reference that one with priority over bootstrap's.